# Presto server on AWS - Cannot connect to discovery server

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto

Trying to run Presto coordinator server with discovery server embedded on AWS CDH4 cluster

config.properties:

```
coordinator=true
datasources=jmx
http-server.http.port=8000
presto-metastore.db.type=h2
presto-metastore.db.filename=var/db/MetaStore
task.max-memory=1GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://ip-10-0-0-11:8000
```

When server starts it can't register itself with discovery (relevant logs):

```
2013-11-08T19:38:38.193+0000     WARN   main    Bootstrap   Warning: Configuration property 'discovery.uri' is deprecated and should not be used
2013-11-08T19:38:38.968+0000     INFO   main    Bootstrap   discovery-server.enabled                                  false                             true
2013-11-08T19:38:38.975+0000     INFO   main    Bootstrap   discovery.uri                                             null                              http://ip-10-0-0-11:8000          Discovery service base URI
2013-11-08T19:38:40.916+0000    ERROR   Discovery-0 io.airlift.discovery.client.CachingServiceSelector  Cannot connect to discovery server for refresh (collector/general): Lookup of collector failed for http://ip-10-0-0-11:8000/v1/service/collector/general
2013-11-08T19:38:42.556+0000    ERROR   Discovery-1 io.airlift.discovery.client.CachingServiceSelector  Cannot connect to discovery server for refresh (presto/general): Lookup of presto failed for http://ip-10-0-0-11:8000/v1/service/presto/general
2013-11-08T19:38:43.854+0000     INFO   main    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector  Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8000
```

Tried to also run standalone Discovery server, same effect. Looks that listener is started after registration attempt is made.

Comment: Same result on cloudera quick start vm image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was wondering if someone would notice this in the logs :) It's actually not a problem. The error appears because the discovery client starts before the discovery server is ready. You'll see "succeeded for refresh" shortly after in the logs which shows that it's working. We will fix the log message eventually but it's purely a cosmetic issue.

Comment: Ok, running both, discovery and worker on the same node works for both AWS and cloudera demo vm. In this case I can just ignore the error.

My main goal, however, was to run Presto on 5 nodes cluster and having errors above, second node can not connect to discovery node and thus will not participate in querying. Is there anything else? I'm adding another relevant log from the second node.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it matches the problem described. I still can't run presto in distributed mode, please see if you can answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912298/presto-server-cannot-connect-to-discovery-server-for-announce) question. Thanks.