# Presto server - Cannot connect to discovery server for announce

Tags: presto

Trying to run Presto with standalone Coordinator/several worker nodes. Coordinator node starts, but can not announce itself to the Discovery service (running on the same node). Starting presto worker on another node also fails to announce to the Discovery service and thus this problem when qyerying: *failed: No nodes available to run query*.

Coordinator/Discovery node config:

```
coordinator=true
datasources=jmx
http-server.http.port=8000
presto-metastore.db.type=h2
presto-metastore.db.filename=var/db/MetaStore
task.max-memory=1GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://10.0.0.11:8000
```

Startup log:

```
2013-11-11T16:54:57.999+0000     INFO   main    com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer     ======== SERVER STARTED ========
2013-11-11T16:54:58.002+0000    ERROR   Announcer-0 io.airlift.discovery.client.Announcer   Cannot connect to discovery server for announce: Announcement failed with status code 404:         <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /v1/announcement/presto-coordinator. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
```

Server seems be running on port 8000:

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-11 ~]# curl http://10.0.0.11:8000
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
...
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Presto</h1>
    </div>
...
```

P.S. Seeing the same problem on Azure cluster, doesn't look to be Amazon or networking issue.

This is follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867489/presto-server-on-aws-cannot-connect-to-discovery-server) question where Presto would work fine with Coordinator/Worker on the same node (but still having the problem above).

Comment: Is 10.0.0.11:8000 the coordinator? Does the coordinator successfully announce itself to the embedded discovery server? Please verify that discovery.uri all point at the coordinator.

Comment: Yes, 10.0.0.11:8000 is the coordinator and embedded discovery server. No, it cannot announce itself to the embedded discovery server, attached log fragment is 10.0.0.11 coordinator/discovery server startup.
In this case it's only one node startup and it's discovery.uri is correct (mentioned in the question). The rest of datanodes also have correct discovery.uri, but I can not figure out why it can't announce itself first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After reading your question and comment several times, I finally realized that this is a bug in the discovery server (both embedded and standalone) that causes dynamic announcements not to work when `node.id` (in the `node.properties` file) is not a UUID. We have never noticed this bug because we always use UUIDs.

The clue here is the "Problem accessing `/v1/announcement/presto-coordinator`" message. This means `node.id` is set to `presto-coordinator`, which should be perfectly valid, but the dynamic announcement resource tries to parse it as a UUID and fails, causing the 404 response to the `PUT` request.

We will fix this soon, but for now the workaround is to set `node.id` to a UUID. You can run the `uuid` or `uuidgen` command line utility to generate them. Make sure each worker has a different value for `node.id`.

Comment: Thanks, David! This fixed the issue and I can run presto with 1 coordinator and 5 workers.

Comment: @DavidPhillips - any thoughts on this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852336/presto-prestodb-query-failed-catalog-hive-does-not-exist?noredirect=1#comment44109104_27852336 ?  I have changed all the node.ids to UUIDs using uuidgen as mentioned above.  Still having issues.

Comment: Please ask on the user group or file an issue on GitHub: https://prestodb.io/community.html

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the following is there in your coordinator config.properties

`discovery-server.enabled=true`

Answer (score 0):

To run in the same node, you should modify the Coordinator/Discovery node config:

```
coordinator=true
datasources=jmx,hive
http-server.http.port=8080
presto-metastore.db.type=h2
presto-metastore.db.filename=var/db/MetaStore
task.max-memory=1GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://v125203052.bja:8080
```

and DO NOT run the discovery-server alone. 
Then run the client and you will be able to execute the query correctly.